# selfhosted WCF-Service + client certificate authentication

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, authentication

i'm trying to implement a self hosted WCF-Service which should use client authentication by certificate. Unfortunately the authentication fails. The log file says, that the client does not provide a certificate. If try to reach the service through firefox, it says: "Error 403 - Forbidden".

The following code shows the configuration via the app-config file.

```
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="sslbehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" /> 
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <clientCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="ChainTrust" trustedStoreLocation="CurrentUser"/>
        </clientCertificate>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="cert-thumb-print" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My"/>
      </serviceCredentials>            
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>

endpoint address="https://localhost:443/service" binding="wsHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="BindingForResultPost" contract="MobD.IEndpointService" />
```

The error msg: System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpsClientCertificateNotPresent.aspx

i guess that i've created and installed my certs correctly.

I would be very grateful for every hint...

Kind regards,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

You say that when you try and reach it through Firefox you get a 403. Has Firefox got the client certificate installed?

What is the Http sub code? My guess is you are getting a 403.7 (which means the client certificate is not installed, or not being presented by the browser), 403.16 (client certificate is untrusted), 403.17 (client certificate has expired) or possibly 403.13 (client certificate revoked).

One problem I have seen - on servers that do not have outgoing web access - is you get one of the above 403 codes (can't remember which) because the server is unable to get a certificate revocation list - and so it declines all certificates. This check can be disabled, but obviously there are security considerations to be aware of.

Comment: Shouldn't firefox ask me for a certificate when i'm connecting to the service? How can retrieve the subcode? e.g. 403.x - i just see the main code... i've already tried using fiddler, but unfortunately the output wasn't very helpful. Client cert as well as its root-ca is installed on the client-machine.

Comment: Is this a Windows box? Firefox doesn't use the Windows certificate store, as IE and Chrome do. It has its own store, so you'll need to install it there too (or test with one of IE or Chrome). Assuming you are using IIS7 or above, I think you have to configure detailed error codes - for security reasons it isn't enabled by default as it gives too much info away for public consumption.

Comment: Yep, it's Windows. I've already tried to put the certs in the certifiate store of firefox. It seems like the WCF-Service does not ask for a certificate. Where can i activiate the details error code? it's a self-hosted application - is the configuration of iis nescessary?

Comment: Ah - it's self hosted. Not sure how to enable detailed error messages, but you could try setting up WCF tracing and see if that gives you the extra info you need. It may be worth hosting this in IIS (e.g. using Windows Process Activation Services) as an experiment to see if you can get to the bottom of this. I'm not sure about debugging the SSL side of a WCF service if it is self hosted.

Comment: Well, i've tested the whole thing in different browsers. IE,FF and Chrome were not able to ask for a client certificate. The only browser who has shown a popup was safari. I've tried to implement a testclient. Unfortunately the authentication failed again with the 403 error. Does anybody has an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: OK - slight change of plan - lets check the browsers: can you set up a simple site with one page on IIS, and in the SSL configuration section, now require both server and client certificates. Try hitting this with the other web browsers. If they still don't prompt then this may be a browser/client cert setup issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the below steps on where to install the client certificates:

You need to have the client certificate as follows:

On the client machine :

Current User --> Personal folder should have client certificate MyClientCert.pfx installed

On Server machines:

Local Machine --> TrusterPeople should have MyClientCert.cer installed

Make sure that the setup is correct. I see that you have the client certificate in the TrustedPeople of current user. Hope now its clear on the certificates installation

Please refer to this **[LINK](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/89e8168e-731e-4322-bd0e-2d5c4c2b3657)** that explains a bit on client certificate being installed and how to tell the browser to pick one from the store:

NOTE: When to use the .pfx and .cer files

Comment: I've installed the certs exactly that way u decribed. The same error occurs. The client is not asked for his certificate. Is the behaviour configuration correct?

Comment: Is the client and server both on same machine in your case? If not then your store for the client certificates should be local machine rather than current user. Ex: <certificate findValue="client.com" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>

Comment: No, client and server aren't on the same machine. Is there any possibility to get any log files?

Comment: In that case the client certificates need to be on the local machine store on the server. Change that to reflect in your app.config. Would be easy if you can update your question to contain both the client, server config files

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign port rights in Windows when you are self hosting WCF services.

See this article on MSDN: [How to: Configure a Port with an SSL Certificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733791.aspx)

You can also use [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html) to check the port status.